# React JSX error : Unclosed regular expression on standard html tags ( <p> <h1> <div> )

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This question has been asked before, and there's a body of people writing about it - but 2hrs searching and i couldn't find a simple explanation anywhere so i'm asking it again.

The build is failing for a 'React JSX error : Unclosed regular expression' and flagging the "/" in each closed div (so `</h1>` ). I've tried wrapping nearly everything in div's but to no avail. It seems such an odd spot to flag an error.

```
const Content = (props) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Container className="mt-5">
      <h1>The World Needs something:</h1> 
        <h3>Short</h3> 
      </Container> 

    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Content;
```

I've also created a jsfiddle where is flags the issue, but no matter how much i search i can't find how to fix it. I'm fairly new to React so explain it like i'm five format would be good. Also it'll help make sure anyone in the future can understand how to fix this issue.

Comment: How do you post-process this file?

Comment: Does the file have the .jsx extension?

Comment: h1 is not a div!

Answer (score 0):

You are given tag as reactjs but it's looking like you mixed both react js web and react native. 
If you are working with React native remove h1 and h3 and use https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/text.html#h1
if you are doing react Hs remove fragment and container and place divorce tags

Answer (score 0):

i've led everyone, and myself on a wild goose chase. the site broke earlier but i must have been loading a cached version.

I've no idea why it flags an error on jsfiddle, but it loads fine on our site now.

Sorry for the trouble, but thanks for your replies